# Stand-alone units with package siunitx

Tags: siunitx

To avoid writing down all the units and the associated powers, I wanted to start to use the `siunitx` package but I have a problem.
In fact :

- The pressure is `\SI{10}{\mega\pascal}` = "The pressure is 10 MPa"
- The pressure is `10 \mega\pascal` = "The pressure is 10"

In other words, I can't write the units without using `\SI{expression}{units}`, which is quite restrictive.
Does someone have any idea to fix it ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!  That's by design: `siunitx`'s units only work inside `siunitx`'s commands.  `\SI{10}{\mega\pascal}` is the correct syntax and you should use that

Comment: You can use units with `\si {\mega\pascal}`, or, simpler, `\si{\MPa}`, but to be sure to have the correct spacing between number and unit, it's better to use `\SI{10}{\MPa}`.

Answer (score 9):

You can load the package with option `free-standing-units`, then define

```latex
\DeclareSIUnit\megapascal{\mega\pascal}
```

to allow `\megapascal` in document scope. You might also want `unit-optional-argument` to allow `\megapascal[10]`, or `space-before-unit` to allow `10\megapascal` to work.

I recommend the standard interface in which units are an argument to `\SI`.

Comment: I'm assuming the `unit-optional-argument` method would produce the space in 10 000  and make a box with the number and unit together (?), for example, where `10\megapascal` would not?

Comment: @likethevegetable Yes

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer:

```
\usepackage{siunitx}

\sisetup{decimalsymbol=comma,expproduct=.,seperr}
```

I don't know why it works, but it works! I took all the packages of a friend that could do it and removed it one after the other to figure out that the `\sisetup` command allows me to do what I wanted.

Comment: The `\sisetup`command you used here contains options that were only available in version 1 of the `siunitx` package. If you use this with a more recentversion, you will get a corresponding warning message, such as "Version 1 option ... detected." Internally, the `siunitx` package now seems to use `version-1-compatibility`. Thus, you can achieve the same behavior, if you use `\usepackage[version-1-compatibility]{siunitx}` instead of the two lines of code you showed in your answer. However, [Joseph Wright's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/593670/134144)  is definitely preferrable.

Answer (score -1):

To only get the units, you can do:

```
\SI{}{\mega\pascal}
```

or (the more correct one):

```
\si{\mega\pascal}
```